# Ubuntu stuck on trial version

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am currently running the trial version on Ubuntu (I am very new to Linux) and I am trying to install Ubuntu to have the full version. I am currently trying to dual booting it with windows. I have two hard drives, an SSD and a 1TB hard drive along with that. I have files on both hard drives on windows that I need to keep. On windows I partitioned the 1TB drive into two parts; the files i need to keep on windows, and Ubuntu on the other part (the part I am trying to get Ubuntu on is free space). I also have a usb flash drive with the trial version of Ubuntu on it.

The problem I am having is that while on the trial of Ubuntu I open the installer tool (that says "Install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS") and install it. It will go through all the installation and ask me to restart my computer. I'll restart my computer, and it will just go to the trial version again.

Note: I have tried various methods of installing such as letting Ubuntu automatically install, or clicking "something else" (which lets you manually partition).

One thing that I did notice that may help solve this issue is that when I am selecting Installation Type, the first option is "Erase Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and reinstall"

Edit* When I unplug the USB from the computer I will get an error stating, "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system" on startup

Comment: You need to unplug the USB.

Comment: When I don't have the usb in, it will give me an error saying, "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system"

Comment: If you are sure you installed Ubuntu,...change boot preference order,

Comment: Do NOT select the "reinstall"! That will wipe the disk of everything else -- bug 1265192.

Comment: I just changed boot preference order and now it works... Thank you!

Comment: @Ravan Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @alimasim feel free to accept my answer  since it solved your problem =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your installation of Ubuntu completed,

`remove live usb` and `change the boot preference order`.

Comment: @Fabby ....done!=)